# Determine the arity of a function handle and currying

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, currying, arity

Is there any way to determine the arity of a function and/or curry functions in MATLAB?  I can't find any documentation on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for nargin?

For example,

```
>> nargin('genvarname')

ans =

     2
```

i.e. the function genvarname has an arity of 2

Comment: Awesome!  This is exactly what I needed.  Is there also an `nargout`?

Comment: Note that the output of `nargin` is negative if the function has a _variable number of input arguments_.

Comment: Is there any way to curry a function?  (Partially apply it?)  As in f(x, y), we fix the value of x and call it g(y)?  Other examples include C++ `bind`.

Comment: Found the answer to my second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154271/partial-function-evaluation-in-matlab