# How do I evaluate the function in only one of its variables in Scilab

Tags: scilab

How do I evaluate the function in only one of its variables, that is, I hope to obtain another function after evaluating the function. I have the following piece of code.

```
deff ('[F] = fun (x, y)', 'F = x ^ 2-3 * y ^ 2 + x * y ^ 3');
fun (4, y)
```

I hope to get 16-3y ^ 2 + 4y ^ 3

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is to write `x = f(4,y)`, and later just do `x(2)` to get `-36`, that is called *[partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)*:

> Intuitively, partial function application says "if you fix the first arguments of the function, you get a function of the remaining arguments".

This is a very useful feature, and very common Functional Programming Languages, such as Haskell, but even JS and Python now are able to do it. It is also possible to do this in MATLAB and GNU/Octave using anonymous functions ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154271/partial-function-evaluation-in-matlab)). In Scilab, however, this feature is **not** available.

**Workround**

Nonetheless, Scilab itself uses a workarounds to carry a function with its arguments without fully evaluating. You see this being used in `ode()`, `fsolve()`, `optim()`, and others:

1. Create a `list` containing the function and the arguments to partial evaluation: `list(f,arg1,arg2,...,argn)`
2. Use another function to evaluate such list and the last argument: `evalPartList(list(...),last_arg)`

The implementation of `evalPartList()` can be something like this:

```
function y = evalPartList(fList,last_arg)
    //fList: list in which the first element is a function
    //last_arg: last argument to be applied to the function

    func = fList(1);          //extract function from the list

    y = func(fList(2:$),last_arg); //each element of the list, from second 
                                   //to last, becomes an argument
endfunction
```

You can test it on Scilab's console:

```
--> deff ('[F] = fun (x, y)', 'F = x ^ 2-3 * y ^ 2 + x * y ^ 3');

--> x = list(fun,4)
 x  = 
       x(1)

[F]=       x(1)(x,y)

       x(2)

   4.

--> evalPartList(x,2)
 ans  =
   36.
```

This is a very simple implementation for `evalPartList()`, and you have to be careful not to exceed or be short on the number of arguments.

Comment: Could you explain why `deff('z=x(y)','z=f(4,y)')` in scilab  is not the same as `x = @(y) f(4,y)` in matlab ?

Comment: Hmmm... no, because I do believe they are semantically the same.

Comment: Then isn't it a partial application ?

Comment: @PTRK No. You have to *actually* apply something and get a function as output. In your case, you define a function whose definition is to call another function. What if you want to change the `4`? It is hard coded there. In MATLAB if you write `f = @(y,x) (@(x) (...))`, then do `a = f(4)`, `a` will be a function itself, hence `a(2)` will work. You can make `[ls{1,1}, ls{1,2}, ls{1,3}] = deal(f(2), f(3), f(4))` to make it partially applied to different values and stored in the same cell array. The caveat is that the function definition has to allow it to be partially applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you're asking, you can't.

What you're looking is called symbolic (or formal) computational mathematics, because you don't pass actual numerical values to functions.

Scilab is numerical software so it can't do such thing. But there is a toolbox [scimax](https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/scimax/) ([installation guide](https://scilab.in/scilab-symbolic-toolbox)) that rely on a the free formal software wxmaxima.

## BUT

An ugly, stupid but still sort of working solution is to takes advantages of strings :

```
function F = fun (x, y) // Here we define a function that may return a constant or string depending on the input
  fmt = '%10.3E'
  if (type(x)==type('')) & (type(y)==type(0)) // x is string is 
    ys = msprintf(fmt,y)
    F = x+'^2 - 3*'+ys+'^2 + '+x+'*'+ys+'^3'
  end
  if (type(y)==type('')) & (type(x)==type(0)) // y is string so is F
    xs = msprintf(fmt,x)
    F = xs+'^2 - 3*'+y+'^2 + '+xs+'*'+y+'^3'
  end
  if (type(y)==type('')) & (type(x)==type('')) // x&y are strings so is F
    F = x+'^2 - 3*'+y+'^2 + '+x+'*'+y+'^3'
  end
  if (type(y)==type(0)) & (type(x)==type(0)) // x&y are constant so is F
    F = x^2 - 3*y^2 + x*y^3
  end
endfunction

// Then we can use this 'symbolic' function
deff('F2 = fun2(y)',' F2 = '+fun(4,'y'))

F2=fun2(2) // does compute fun(4,2)
disp(F2)
```